# XMPP on IOS: How can I request for more presences

Tags: ios, xmpp

I am making a IOS application to chat with others facebook users.

- I open the connection.
- Authenticate the user.
- Go online sending the presense to the server.
- Receive the presence of the others users.

The problem is: The server only send to me 8 users.

How can I make a XMPP request for more presences, using the IOS framework?
The XMPP have a automatic request?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have more than 8 friends?  Have you tried with another client?  If you see presence from more than 8 users, then it's definitely your client.  If you look closely, you might find that you're not reading from the socket again after you've received your first IP packet; 8 presences might be just about 1500 bytes  (1 typical MTU) on the wire with overhead.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help.
My Facebook user have more than 8 friends. The presences receive is not the friends, it's the ID's like -59123654. then I get the IQ with function "didReceiveIQ" and connect the user with the code.  De users's code I receive is 8, and IQ's is 2. I need request for more users. I don't know if this is automatic in the XMPP IOS.